# Material UI radioButton

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a radioButton from **Material UI(0.18.1)**.
The color props for the  component is not working.

```
<RadioButton
   className="no-filter-btn"
   label="No Filter"
   color="primary"
   fullWidth
   onCheck={this.noFilter}
/>
```

This is the **older** Version of material UI.

Answer (score 0):

Following to https://v0.material-ui.com/v0.18.1/#/components/radio-button
RadioButton Properties does not have color props. You should try to override css style.

Answer (score 0):

Color property is not a prop you can pass into the Component rather use style property like:

```
style={`color` : `${primary}`}
```

Comment: I tried adding the style property, the radio button is working , but when it's clicked , the button is not highlighted